# Using Ruby CSV to extract one column

Tags: ruby, csv

I've been trying to work with getting a single column out of a csv file.

I've gone through the documentation, http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html
but still don't really understand how to use it.

If I use `CSV.table`, the response is incredibly slow compared to `CSV.read`. I admit the dataset I'm loading is quite large, which is exactly the reason I only want to get a single column from it.

My request is simply currently looks like this

```
@dataTable = CSV.table('path_to_csv.csv')
```

and when I debug I get a response of

```
#<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:2104 >
```

The documentation says I should be able to use [by_col()](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Table.html#method-i-by_col#by_col-method), but when I try to output

```
<%= debug @dataTable.by_col('col_name or index') %>
```

It gives me "undefined method 'col' error"

Can somebody explain to me how I'm supposed to use CSV? and if there is a way to get columns faster using 'read' instead of 'table'?

I'm using Ruby 1.92, which says that it is using fasterCSV, so I don't need to use the FasterCSV gem.

Comment: You might be getting it wrong because by_col doesn't take any arguments.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To pluck a column out of a csv I'd probably do something like the following:

```
col_data = []
CSV.foreach(FILENAME) {|row| col_data << row[COL_INDEX]}
```

That should be substantially faster than any operations on CSV.Table

Answer (score 15):

You can get the values from single column of the csv files using the following snippet.

```
@dataTable = CSV.table('path_to_csv.csv')
@dataTable[:columnname]
```

Comment: this is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works for me (I'm using the OP's variable name here):

```
@dataTable = CSV.read('path_to_csv.csv')
@dataTable.by_col!
p @dataTable.values_at('Field1')
```

This prints all the values in the column `Field1`, as an array of arrays with one element: `[value1],[value2],[value3]...` and so on. So

```
p @dataTable.values_at('Field1').flatten
```

will print all the values in the column `Field1` in a single array.

If you want to loop through all the fields in a table one by one, then here's one way to do that. First, you have to convert so that indexes reference columns rather than rows, with `by_col!`. Then indexes will reference columns instead of rows, and you can do something like this:

```
@dataTable = CSV.read('path_to_csv.csv')
@dataTable.by_col!

0.upto(@dataTable.headers.size - 1) do |i|
  p @dataTable.values_at(i).flatten.compact.size # Or whatever you want here
end
```

This is a way to work up summary values from a CSV file, which can then be used to create a pivot table. If there's a requirement to input data from a CSV file and output summary data in the form of a pivot table, this might be a straightforward way to go.