# ruby, extract a spreadsheet column and put it in an array

Tags: ruby, xlsx

I have an xlsx spreadsheet that has database information, like table names and other info,  is there any way how to extract the whole column called Table_Names and put it in array of strings ?

UPDATE,

I could get only rows, my question how to get a special column :

```
require 'spreadsheet'    
Spreadsheet.open('MyTestSheet.xls') do |book|
  book.worksheet('Sheet1').each do |row|
    break if row[0].nil?
    puts row.join(',')
  end
end
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why is this tagged [csv]?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Find a xlsx parser and look in its readme for sample code.

Comment: I found for rows, but could not find any to extract a column.

Comment: Well, just iterate rows and take a value of that one column from each row. Similar to how you would process an array of arrays.

Comment: I added an update in my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Ruby CSV to extract one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969514/using-ruby-csv-to-extract-one-column), if you already have the rows. A similar approach should work

Comment: the duplicate solution works with CSV files not excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

to deal with excel files use the gem spreadsheet and add require 'spreadsheet'

Thanks.